# Are there any smart IDEs for perl in linux environmnent and also for c++?

Tags: c++, linux, perl

Currently I am using CentOS 5.5 and I am looking for intelligent IDEs for Perl and C++ coding.

Comment: IDE **s** or an IDE for both? Getting two is dead easy, you just grab any that work well (plenty of C++ IDEs, such as KDevelop, C::B, ...). Getting one for both a bit harder.

Comment: If you want separate IDEs, Padre is a good IDE for Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you give [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) a try?

Komodo is a good C++/C/Perl/Python/PHP/JavaScript/.. IDE, and it has a precious feature: vi emulation!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Eclipse with CDT plugin for C++?. I don't sure how it's good for perl, but for C++ in Linux environment is pretty good.

vi/vim from other hand will good for all languages :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org/). It's Eclipse based and has built in debugger.

Me, I just use [vim](http://www.vim.org). However, I learned programming on a [Wyse 60](http://interlynxis.com/images/wy-60.jpg) terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As @Davis mentioned [Eclipse-EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org/) integration is really good for programming Perl on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a good promising generic IDE for most of the languages. The plugin community is simply amazing. Codeblocks and Netbeans are good for C++. Netbeans also supports other languages like PHP, JavaScript, Java etc.